# How to solve "sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation"?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, digital-ocean, ssh-keys

Configuring a new Digital Ocean droplet with SSH keys. When I run `ssh-copy-id` this is what I get:

```
ssh-copy-id user@012.345.67.89
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
user@012.345.67.89's password: 

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'user@012.345.67.89'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

However, when I then attempt to ssh in, this happens:

```
ssh user@012.345.67.89
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
user@012.345.67.89's password:
```

Upon entering the password, I am logged in just fine, but this of course defeats the purpose of creating the SSH key in the first place. I decided to take a look at the ssh-agent server-side and here's what I get:

```
user@012.345.67.89:~# eval `ssh-agent -s`
Agent pid 5715
user@012.345.67.89:~# ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

user/.ssh/authorized_keys does contain an ssh-rsa key entry, as well, but `find -name "keynamehere"` returns nothing.

Answer (score 519, accepted):

Run `ssh-add` on the client machine, that will add the SSH key to the agent.

Confirm with `ssh-add -l` (again on the client) that it was indeed added.

Comment: It did not entirely fix it here as I use `gpg-agent` for SSH functionality. I already have a `enable-ssh-support` in `gpg-agent.conf` but still same error message. I have found on mailing list to run this: `gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye`: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=835394

Comment: I just had to kill the gpg-agent and then run it again.

Comment: When you generate a new SSH key, `ssh-add` must be invoked for the `ssh-agent` to become aware of the new private key (per https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent).

Comment: I had to correct the permissions of the private key, then do ssh-add.


WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!

Permissions 0640 for '/home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.

$ chmod 600 /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa

$ ssh-add

then work succefuly.

Thank You.

Comment: I also had to kill gpg-agent as @Subin suggested in order to get `gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye` to work again as expected. You can safely terminate gpg-agent easily using `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` without having to go manually searching for the correct process id.

Comment: I had to follow @Roland's suggestion (I added it to my `fish` config) and also had to update my `pinentry-program` in `gpg-agent.conf`. Despite `/usr/bin/pinentry-gtk-2` being installed, it didn't work, so I had to change it to `/usr/bin/pinentry-gnome3`.

Answer (score 264):

After upgrading Fedora 26 to 28 I faced same issue.
And following logs were missing

```
/var/log/secure
/var/log/messages
```

**ISSUE:**

```
antop@localmachine  ~  ssh root@ocp1.example.com
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
root@ocp1.example.com's password:
```

**error message is not pointing actual issue. Issue resolved by**

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
```

Comment: My `.ssh/` didn't have the required permissions because I had created it myself manually.

Comment: Seems that some versions don't allow your keys to be visible to other users. Thanks!

Comment: if .ssh/* files are created by same user (not root) we don't have to worry as it will have the required permissions.

Comment: I moved my .ssh dir from an OS to a fresh linux install and I could not push with git. Using this solution worked for me.

Comment: I can confirm; I moved the ssh directory from WSL to a fresh PopOS install. Changing the permissions using the mentioned solution worked for me.

Comment: Holly shit thank you. Lame that even with -vv ssh doesn't complain about perms..... seriously...

Comment: I copied my ssh key from windows to linux and hence it didnt have correct permission I guess. This worked.

Comment: Yes, this is it. Amazingly, it's still relevant (and the error message still misleading) in 2023.

Answer (score 205):

I was having the same problem in ***Linux Ubuntu 18***. After the update from ***Ubuntu 17.10***, every git command would show that message.

The way to solve it is to make sure that you have the correct permission on the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`.

Check the current chmod number by using `stat --format '%a' <file>`.
It should be **600** for `id_rsa`  and **644** for `id_rsa.pub`.

To change the permission on the files use

```
chmod 600 id_rsa
chmod 644 id_rsa.pub
```

That solved my issue with the update.

Comment: I faced this problem after migrating Ubuntu from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS, this solution worked for me.

Comment: Same here, after updating Ubuntu to 18.04 I faced this problem. This solution fix it.

Comment: When does `id_rsa.pub` is used in the client authentication process?

Comment: If you have many keys, you should use something like this inside `~/.ssh`: `chmod 600 id_*`

Comment: Check the key first
$ ssh-add -l
if everything okay then update those permissions.

Comment: I used multiple computers, so to keep things simple, I have uploaded my ssh keys to my cloud drive. If i need to switch computer, i just need to download the ssh key, apply this and voila, thanks

Comment: The file id_rsa.pub is never used in the process so changing its permissions may be misleading.

Answer (score 63):

Run the below command to resolve this issue.

It worked for me.

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 36):

I once had a problem just like yours, and this is how I solved it through the following steps.

1. chmod 700 ~/.ssh
2. chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
3. ssh-copy-id user@ip
4. ssh-agent -s
5. ssh-add

Comment: just the chmod 600 of my key files where sufficient.
what a stupid error message is that then from the SSH communication!!!

Comment: **OMG.** I'm flabbergasted that OpenSSH just ambiguously reports `"agent refused operation"` for insecure keyfile permissions. `</double_facepalm>`

Comment: Yup. This is what fixed it for me too. I came back to working on my servers like 5 months later and it seems the changes in OpenSSH need more strict file perms. Kudos to @Dean for figuring this one out! Upvoting!

Comment: Trying `ssh-add -vvv ~/.ssh/keys/<mykey>` first is also a good way to check for correct rights upfront, because this command actually tells you what is wrong (for example “Permissions 0644 for '.ssh/<mykey>' are too open.”).

Answer (score 22):

I had the error when using gpg-agent as my ssh-agent and using a gpg subkey as my ssh key https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#gpg-agent.

I suspect that the problem was caused by having an invalid pin entry tty for gpg caused by my sleep+lock command used in my sway config

`bindsym $mod+Shift+l exec "sh -c 'gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye>/dev/null; systemctl suspend; swaylock'"`

or just the sleep/suspend

Reset the pin entry tty to fix the problem

`gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye > /dev/null`

and the fix for my sway sleep+lock command:

`bindsym $mod+Shift+l exec "sh -c 'gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye>/dev/null; systemctl suspend; swaylock; gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye > /dev/null'"`

Comment: Thank you. I had this problem a few days ago, I use gpg as you and have commented `gpg-connect-agent updaterstartuptty /bye > /dev/null` on my ~/.zshrc, uncommenting this line solved my problem.

Comment: You legend.  How the hell did you find a fix for this? it's so obscure!

Answer (score 20):

`eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`
To first start the ssh agent

`ssh-add`
To then add the ssh key

Answer (score 8):

**To this error:**

```
# git pull
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).    
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

> Verify or add again the public key in Github account > profile > ssh.

**I solved like this:**

```
# chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# ls  ~/.ssh/id_rsa -ls  
4 -r--------. 1 reinaldo reinaldo 1679 Jul 26  2017 /home/reinaldo/.ssh/id_rsa

# git pull                                 
remote: Counting objects: 35, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Total 35 (delta 9), reused 34 (delta 9), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (35/35), done.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

There could be various reason for getting the SSH error:

> sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation

Some of them could be related to the issues highlighted by the other answers (see this thread answers), some of them could be hidden and thus would require a closer investigation.

In my case I've got the following error message:

> sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
>
> user@website.domain.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

The only way to find the real problem was to invoke the **-v** verbose option which resulted in printing a lot of debugging info:

```
debug1: Connecting to website.domain.com [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.website.domain.com type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.website.domain.com-cert type -1
```

Please note that the line saying `key_load_public: No such file or directory` is referring the next line and not the previous line.

So what SSH really says is that it could not find the public key file named `id_rsa.website.domain.com-cert` and that seemed to be the problem in my case since my public key file did not contain the `-cert` suffix.

Long story short: the fix in my case was just to make sure that the public key file was named as expected. I could never suspected that without debugging the connection.

The bottom line is **USE THE SSH VERBOSE MODE** (-v option) to figure out what is wrong, there could be various reasons, none that could be found on this/another thread.

Answer (score 4):

First
`ssh-add`
then
`ssh user@ip`

this worked for me

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was that GNOME keyring was holding an invalid passphrase for the ssh key to be used. After spending indecent amount of time troubleshooting this issue I ran `seahorse` and found the entry to hold empty string. I can only guess that it was caused by mistyping the passphrase at first use some time earlier, and then probably cancelling the requester or so in order to fall back to command line. Updating the entry with correct passphrase immediately solved the problem. Deleting that entry (from "login" keyring) and reentering passphrase at that first prompt (and checking the appropriate checkbox) solves this too. Now agent gets the correct passphrase from the unlocked at login keyring named "login" and neither asks for passphrase nor "refuses operation" anymore. Of course YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

**Beware of how you name your ssh key files**

If you have more than one key pair, you may be using `ssh-keygen` with the `-f <key name>` to name the output files. In my case, I was naming my keys like `username@organization` and `username@organization.pub`, which helps to keep multiple key pairs organized.

The problem is that the ssh agent doesn't like the `@` character.

In my case this was causing the `sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation` error, and was preventing the session keyring to interact with the ssh agent.

Renaming my key files to `username_at_organization` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I got a `sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation` error as well. But in my case the problem was a wrong `pinentry` path.

In my `${HOME}/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` the `pinentry-program` property was pointing to an old pinentry path. Correcting the path there and restarting the `gpg-agent` fixed it for me.

I discovered it by following the logs with `journalctl -f`. There where log lines like the following containing the wrong path:

```
Jul 02 08:37:50 my-host gpg-agent[12677]: ssh sign request failed: No pinentry <GPG Agent>
Jul 02 08:37:57 my-host gpg-agent[12677]: can't connect to the PIN entry module '/usr/local/bin/pinentry': IPC connect call failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.   Run **ssh-add** on the client machine.
Then repeat command  **ssh-copy-id userserver@012.345.67.89**

Answer (score 1):

According to Github security blog RSA keys with SHA-1 are no longer accepted.

Use the following command to create new SSH key with ECDSAencryption and add it to Github.

ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521 -C "your_email@example.com"

original answer with details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498990/cannot-resolve-swift-packages-after-15th-march-2022-in-xcode/71498991#71498991)

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was a wrong copy/paste of the public key into Gitlab. The copy generated an extra return. Make sure what you paste is a one-line key.

Answer (score 0):

*I need to share, as I spent too much time looking for a solution*

> Here was the solution : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/351742/215375

I was using this command :

```
ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@example.com"
```

gnome-keyring does not support the generated key.

**Removing the `-o` argument solved the problem.**

Answer (score 0):

What worked here : on the client

1) ssh-add

2) ssh-copy-id user@server

The keys has been created some time ago with plain "ssh-keygen -t rsa"
I sw the error message because I copied across my ssh public key from client to server (with ssh-id-copy) without running ssh-add first, since I erroneously assumed I'd added them some time earlier.

Answer (score 0):

quick note for those recently upgrading to "modern" ssh version [OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d FIPS  10 Sep 2019] - supplied with fedora 31, seems not to be anymore accepting old DSA SHA256 keys (mine are dated 2006!) - created a new rsa key, public added to authorized, private on client, and everything works perfectly.

thanks for previous suggestions, especially the ssh -v has been  very useful

Comment: You should definitely get rid of DSA keys or RSA keys <2048 bits. There are ways to allow OpenSSH to use these older keys, but IMO the ONLY time you should enable a legacy protocol is when connecting to hardware that simply can't be updated to use a newer encryption method (and that hardware probably needs replaced TBH). I have a "smart" network connected PDU (power delivery unit), and it only supports some insecure ciphers, so I have a specific exception in my ssh_config for that host, but I also put it onto a separate VLAN that doesn't talk to the internet because it is a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, there can be multiple reasons for this error.

If you are using [SSH with Smart Card (PIV)](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1523343), and adding the card to ssh-agent with
`ssh-add -s /usr/lib64/pkcs11/opensc-pkcs11.so`
you may get the error
`sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation`
from ssh if the PIV authentication has expired, or if you have removed and reinserted the PIV card.

In that case, if you try to do another `ssh-add -s` you will still get an error:
`Could not add card "/usr/lib64/opensc-pkcs11.so": agent refused operation`

According to [RedHat Bug 1609055 - pkcs11 support in agent is clunky](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1609055), you instead need to do

```
ssh-add -e /usr/lib64/opensc-pkcs11.so
ssh-add -s /usr/lib64/opensc-pkcs11.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this is OpenSSH v9.0's new default of NTRU primes + x25519 key exchange, in combination with gpg-agent (at least, as at v2.2.32).

To work-around, disable the new key exchange algortihm (and thus it's security benefit) thus:

```
ssh -o 'KexAlgorithm -sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com' [...]
```

(or the same in SSH config.)

cf. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/701131/use-ntrux25519-key-exchange-with-gpg-agent

Answer (score 0):

This could cause by 1Passsword not support `ssh-rsa` key exchange. They support newer `rsa-sha-512` and `rsa-sha-256` with security considerations.

https://1password.community/discussion/comment/632712/#Comment_632712

Answer (score 0):

Just to toss another cause into the ring...

My env was configured to use a Gemalto card...but I had an old keypair named `id_rsa_gemalto_old(.pub)` in my `~/.ssh/` and that -- having `gemalto` in the name -- was enough for `git fetch` to result in `sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation`.

(Ubuntu 18.04.6)

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the crypto policy to allow SHA1 *after* the agent was loaded (with something like `update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY`) and the remote host uses SHA1, then the agent needs to be reloaded:

```bash
kill $SSH_AGENT_PID
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it in a strange way. Would like someone to update this answer and explain why.

I was getting the error after ssh from ubuntu 18 to a server with Ubuntu 18.
All permissions are correct.
Pub key is added to the server
SSH key pair is valid, because the below command reported the fingerprint.

```
ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I opened `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and changed a random character in the middle of the key.

`ssh-keygen` reported the pub key remains valid.

Now I can login just by ssh to server, no other modification needed.

Answer (score -1):

This should be rather a SuperUser question.

Right I have the exact same error inside MacOSX SourceTree, however, inside a iTerm2 terminal, things work just dandy.

However, the problem seemed to be that I've got *two* `ssh-agent`s running ;(

The first being `/usr/bin/ssh-agent` (aka MacOSX's) and then also the HomeBrew installed `/usr/local/bin/ssh-agent` running.

Firing up a terminal from SourceTree, allowed me to see the differences in `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, using `lsof` I found the two different `ssh-agent`s and then I was able to load the keys (using `ssh-add`) into the system's default `ssh-agent` (ie. `/usr/bin/ssh-agent`), SourceTree was working again.