# Copied SSH key from PC A doesn't work on PC B

Tags: git, github, ssh

I've created an `SSH` key (on PC A) to access my GitHub repo (works correctly). Then I copied this key to PC B. For some reason, I can't access the repo from the PC B even if the public and private keys are the same.

```
Cloning into 'repo'...
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "/home/milano/.ssh/github-futilestudio" from agent: agent refused operation
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "milano@milano-lenovo" from agent: agent refused operation
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What's the reason behind that?

EDIT

Could the reason be the signature at the end of the SSH key?

```
milano@milano-lenovo
```

which is obviously a name of the PC A.

Comment: to debug ssh issues : run `ssh -v [user]@[target host]` (for example : `ssh -v git@github.com`)

Comment: The key to this error is the text `agent refused operation`. There are multiple possible reasons for this; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/44250002/1256452 for details. Note that, as [VonC suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67955029/1256452), using a *separate key* is often a better idea anyway. You should consider your actual situation and the security implications of separate or shared keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could the reason be the signature at the end of the SSH key?

No, that part is ignored.
Do copy, to be sure, the public key as well as the private one.

Or, ideally, generate a new one dedicated to the second machine (since copying *private* keys is not the best practice)

- If a `ssh -Tv git@github.com` does show you the right private key is considered, check for a difference in environment variable (type set in a CMD). In particular, make sure you don't have `GIT_SSH` set to Windows 10 openSSH.
  Type `where ssh` to make sure Git is using the same openSSH on both machines.
- If a `ssh -Tv git@github.com` does show you the right private key is *not* considered, check if on your first machine you have a `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config`, which should then be replicated on the second one.