# I can't do git push: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I'm not able to perform the `git push` command in a specific project, however, in other projects everything goes well, I don't know what can be done anymore. I have a key, this key is registered on GitHub and apparently the Agent is working.

This is the result when I try to `git push`:

```sh
username@lenovo-ideapad-s145:~/development/projects/Learning-Laravel$ git push
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ED25519 "/home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519" from agent: agent refused operation
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've read the documentation, but it didn't help me much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44250002/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sign_and_send_pubkey%3A+signing+failed+from+agent%3A+agent+refused+operation

Answer (score 1):

Just try to connect the remote Git repository `GitHub` via `ssh` again, e.g:

```
ssh -T git@sofija_personal-github.com
```

Notice: Configure SSH config file!

Create or edit a config configuration file in the /.ssh directory:

`cd /Users/user-name/.ssh && vim config`

Pay attention to the common commands of `vim` or `bash`:

1. Press the letter key "`i`" to edit mode;
2. Press the return key "`esc`" + input the letter "`:wq`": save and exit;

Edit and adding :

```
Host sofija_personal-github.com

   Hostname github.com
   
   User git
   
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   
   UseKeychain yes
   
   IdentityFile /Users/marryme/.ssh/sofija_personal_github_id_rsa
```

Then, just use `git pull --rebase && git push`.

Also, `GitLab` or `Bitbucket` do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be have configured ssh in your machine. Check if this answer helps

[GitHub Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey)

Answer (score 0):

**Error:**

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

With me it was resolved

```
git pull https://github.com/<your-user>/<your repository.git>
```