# Cannot resolve Swift packages after 15th March 2022 in Xcode

Tags: swift, github, swift-package-manager

Package resolution is suddenly failing in Xcode. I tried the following options:

1. Reset cache under `File/Packages/Reset Package Caches`
2. Delete shared SPM cache using `rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm/`

I can see the following error for different packages.

> You're using an RSA key with SHA-1, which is no longer allowed. Please use newer client or a different key type.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After looking around, I found a GitHub security blog post that mentions that from 15th March 2022 onward, RSA keys with SHA-1 are no longer accepted. See the blog post [here](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/).

I tried creating an SSH key with the command provided in GitHub's [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) but Xcode does not accept the `ED25519` encryption method, and commands provided by  GitHub docs do not work.

Eventually I found [this nice post](https://gist.github.com/brennanMKE/8e09593ca4064deab59da807077d8f53) that explains the issue and offers an alternative encryption method, `ECDSA`, that is accepted by Xcode.

Use the following command to create new SSH key and add it to GitHub.

`ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521 -C "your_email@example.com"`

Comment: I've t tried every ssh-keygen command I've found and I still have this issue. I'm pretty sure there's another problem unrelated to the keys.

Comment: @Pacu You cannot create the key or the key does not work with Github?

Comment: I created the keys perfectly. But the problem does not go away. I downgraded Xcode and I was able to work with the same keys that were not working on 13.3

Comment: @Pacu I downloaded Xcode 13.3 and had no issues. Did you set the right key under "Xcode/Preferences/Accounts/Github/SSH Key:" ?

Comment: Xcode 14 and later supports ED25519 keys. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes
*Xcode now supports generating and using externally-generated ED25519 and ECDSA keys to perform git SSH operations. (85009643)*

Comment: I prefer to rely on `ssh-keygen` to choose the bits. Other than that, this (`ssh-keygen -t ecdsa`) solved it for me.