# What is "SwiftPM.SPMRepositoryError error 5"?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I've searched Apple's documentation, open source projects, and Google, and I cannot seem to find any information about `SwiftPM.SPMRepositoryError error 5`. Heck, I can't even find information about `SwiftPM.SPMRepositoryError`.

Does anyone know of documentation for this error or the error codes?

Comment: I downgraded from Xcode 13.3 to Xcode 13.2 and was able to get things working again. I did have to work through an issue related to an old SSH key. For that, I followed through the advice in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71500791 and created a new SSH key with `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 256 -m PEM`. I'm not sure it is related to `SwiftPM.SPMRepositoryError error 5` though...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498990/cannot-resolve-swift-packages-after-15th-march-2022-in-xcode ?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, downgrading from Xcode 13.3 to 13.2 worked for me

Comment: You may post your comment as an answer.

Comment: This answer did help me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71671235/2027279

Comment: I was on 13.3.1. When I switched to 14.0 the problem went away!

Answer (score 16):

What worked for me was switching to `ED25519` key.

I think this is happening now because of the effort to improve Git protocol security on GitHub. You can read more about it here: https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/

There you can see the timeline. The final step was put into motion on Mar 15, 2022 (coincidentally that was just two days before your question)

> Changes made permanent.
> We’ll permanently stop accepting DSA keys. RSA keys uploaded after the cut-off point above will work only with SHA-2 signatures (but again, RSA keys uploaded before this date will continue to work with SHA-1). The deprecated MACs, ciphers, and unencrypted Git protocol will be permanently disabled.

Comment: to confirm, you received the same `SwiftPM.SPMRepositoryError error 5` and resolved it in Xcode 13.3 using the new `ED25519` key?

Comment: @jarrodparkes Yes, I'm on 13.3 and just got this error too and upgraded my key to ED25519 and SPM is working again for me.

Comment: This worked for me thank you. Preferences > Accounts > GitHub Account > SSH Key = id_ed25519 > (Upload if necessary).

Comment: would anyone help me? I'm still having issues with this. even updating the SSH key

Comment: I'm still facing this issue when attempting to update all packages to their latest versions. I've tried switching to both `ECDSA` and `ED25519`, neither have solved the issue for me.

Comment: @VatsalManot did you also try downgrading from Xcode 13.3 to 13.2?

Comment: I tried every ssh-keygen command there was and still facing the same issue. I'm almost sure the keys are not root the problem.

Comment: @jarrodparkes Xcode 13.2 failed with an SSL error.

Comment: @VatsalManot have any of the other methods suggested on this thread been helpful? I'm still anxiously awaiting more information about the error itself

Comment: This worked for me. Make sure after you create the new ssh key that you update Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > Source Control Accounts and select the new ssh key

Comment: I can confirm that switching to ED25519 works in Xcode 13.3

Comment: Do I have to remove RSA key in order for the ED25519 start to work?

Answer (score 12):

This helped in my case:

1. `File` -> `Packages` -> `Reset Package Caches`
2. `File` -> `Packages` -> `Update to Latest Package Versions`

Comment: This helped me, but also you should
3. `File` -> `Packages` -> `Resolve Package Versions`

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me on Xcode 13.3 and 13.3.1 when my team added package dependencies that I didn't have Github access to.  The error message is ambiguous and shows the same number of errors as the number of packages I have in my dependency tree.  But, obtaining access to any repos that I didn't already have access to (which was a smaller number of repos than the error count) resolved the error for me.

I was able to track down the issue by attempting to add another package (anything public like swift-algorithms).  Xcode gave me better error reporting in that process.

Answer (score 1):

Updating `swift-tools-version` in `Package.swift` file worked for me. We've previously been using 5.3, and updating it to 5.5 or 5.6 resolved the problem.

One thing to keep in mind, Apple has deprecated the existing package declaration functions in Swift 5.6 [[1]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/package/dependency), so using this version would result in a lot of new warnings.

Hopefully, this is just a temporary thing, and a proper fix is coming in the next Xcode version.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue.. (project based on a Package.swift file, not a regular .xcodeproj)

Doubted that it would have to do something with GitHub's policy as described above, since I've worked on other projects today without any issues.

Tried to clear the derived data folder, as well as the project's `.swiftpm` folder and even the swiftpm repo cache.. nothing helped.

Tried the same project on another MacBook and worked fine!
Then made a fresh clone of the project in a different folder on the Mac with the issue and worked fine as well.

So finally I just deleted the local `Package.resolved` file, reopened the project in Xcode and everything was back to normal

Comment: thank you for the updates here. im still hoping to find something, from Apple, that gives us more details on the error code itself. I removed the accepted answer mark for now until more information is made available

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the same issue as `Error while fetching remote repositorygit@github.com:***/***.git: An unknown error occurred. reference 'refs/remotes/origin/master' not found (-1)` in Xcode 14.

Here is a small script I made to work around it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74130700/624854.