# Swift packages will not resolve

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I closed Xcode, then ran :

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm/
```

opened xcode, and its been trying to download the packages ever since.

[image]

How do I get my packages to download?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498990/cannot-resolve-swift-packages-after-15th-march-2022-in-xcode ?

Comment: I'm not getting that error. Also, I'm using GitLab and my RSA key is accepted for everything else