# Github cannot connect using ssh

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh

I am setting up my SSH keys with github. Did it numerous times earlier so i am pretty much sure that i am doing it right. But its not working. whenever i clone it just gets stuck there for around 5-10 mins and then returns this

```
Cloning into 'sentry-python'...
Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Ran this command to check what's going on `ssh -vT git@github.com`. One of the many lines in output has this

```
Authenticated to github.com ([13.234.176.102]:22) using "publickey".
```

Followed official documentation for setting up keys. I believe its something else.

**UPDATE:**
HTTPs works fine

Output from: ssh -vT git@github.com

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [13.234.176.102] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-92f10f70
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-92f10f70
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: <SERVER HOST KEY HERE>
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA <KEY HERE> agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA <KEY HERE> agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA <KEY HERE> agent
Authenticated to github.com ([13.234.176.102]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2 for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "en_IN"
```

Okay. So earlier logs where till LANG = "en_IN". Now after altering some permission of my keys here's the updated log.

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [13.234.210.38] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-92f10f70
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-92f10f70
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: <SERVER HOST KEY>
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa <KEY HERE> agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA <KEY HERE> agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA <KEY HERE> agent
Authenticated to github.com ([13.234.210.38]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2 for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "en_IN"
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi targhs! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to github.com closed.
Transferred: sent 3888, received 2812 bytes, in 0.6 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 6234.8, received 4509.3
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: add this values  ServerAliveInterval and ServerAliveCountMax in  .ssh\config file. example :                                                                                   
 `Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 60                                                                 
  ServerAliveCountMax 30`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full output of the "ssh -vT git@github.com" command. Don't paraphrase error messages if you can avoid it.

Comment: I was a bit concerned about security so didn't put it output initially. Replaced all keys and names now. Thanks.

Comment: I can definitely increase the timeout but is it the right thing to do. It shouldn't take so long to do just a simple clone. I believe there's someting else

Comment: It's not clear to me what is happening. The authentication works and the session starts when you use `ssh -Tv`. You could run with `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_PACKET_TRACE=1 GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v"` to get much more detailed information.

Comment: There are always problems when keys get reused (or have ever been used with another account). Can you doublecheck that the user from `ssh -T` (printed in the last lines of the response which you ommit) corresponds to the user you intend to use.

Comment: @bdecaf Thanks for your comment. It was ssh -vT that printed out that log. However i didn't ommit any of the line. I just renamed my username and to 'user' and keys. But yes it was my own user which i intended to use everywhere

Comment: @torek i ran with your said command but it seems like its giving the same output as earlier

Answer (score 1):

[TL;DR link to what might as well be a duplicate here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44250002/1256452)

#### Explanation (long-ish)

You have something new in your edit: `agent refused operation`.  That's the problem here.  You are using an *ssh agent*, and it's the agent that must pass the *private* key (of the public/private key-pair) to ssh so that your ssh can decrypt the challenge that GitHub have sent to your ssh.

The way ssh authentication works (boiled down a bit) is this:

- Your ssh *client* (ssh command) opens a channel to the host (in this case GitHub).
- Your client tells them you'd like to log in as some user name (in this case `git`: GitHub always requires this as a constant).
- Their ssh *server* then says: *I might let you in, provided you prove to me that you have permission.  Send me a public key.*
- Your client then pokes around to look for a public key to send.  It finds one and sends it.
- Their server checks to see if that ssh key is a valid key.  It is; it's registered to you.  But maybe you're not `targhs`.  Maybe you've snagged the public key from the *real* `targhs`, and this connection is from an imposter!  So they want to make sure you're really `targhs`.  They use the *public key* to encrypt a random value, and send you—or rather, your client ssh—the value, challenging you to decrypt it.
- Your client now requires the *private* key.

It's pretty common to have both public and private keys stored in a file on your computer (e.g., on your laptop).  When this is the case, your ssh client can just open and read the private key file, giving it access to that private key.  For security purposes, though, you can do one or both of these two things:

- Not supply the private key at all.  Keep it only in an *agent*.
- Keep the private key in an *encrypted file*, so that a decryption key—separate from the public and private key—is required to *read* the private key.

If you've done either or both of these, your ssh client now needs help.

To get that help, your ssh client can:

- interact directly with you, the user, via the keyboard: this may or may not be permitted; or
- consult an *ssh agent*.

The ssh agent enables ssh clients to interact with you, the user, and provide the (secret) private key, even if it's not on the computer on which you're running ssh, or if it's just encrypted, or whatever.  To do that, the ssh client asks the ssh agent for the key.

Your ssh agent says: *Nuh-uh, not gonna give you the key!*

Why does your ssh agent say that?  That's the mystery here; that's what you have to figure out.  **There are multiple possible reasons.**  Fortunately, they're all pretty well covered in a separate StackOverflow question and answers: see [How to solve "sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44250002/1256452)

Comment: You are correct here. It was having some permission issues. It was my fault. Might be i changed them when doing something else. Fixed that with giving proper permissions. I have posted an update in the question. Thanks for this explanation

Comment: You've changed your question twice now; this answer was for the middle version of the question.

Comment: Yes. apologies for that. I figured out what i was missing so removed that after just couple of minutes after.