# Github Server accepts key but Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: linux, github, ssh, gnupg

I am using a `gpg-agent` to generate some keys I have followed the process described in this [article](https://opensource.com/article/19/4/gpg-subkeys-ssh#:%7E:text=To%20get%20gpg%2Dagent%20to,conf.&text=Optionally%2C%20you%20may%20want%20to,add%20to%20load%20the%20keys). I manage to see that the ssh client does display a public key whith `ssh-add L` which and I have added that ssh key to `github`. So all should be working but they dont.

When I try to connect to github I get a `Permission denied (publickey)`.

I have read almost all of the questions in stackoverflow on the topic like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git)  or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734669/gitgithub-com-permission-denied-publickey), and many more. None of the suggestions seems to be relevant.

I am using this command to debug git `ssh -vT git@github.com` and it gives me this error:

```
debug1: Offering public key: (none) RSA 
SHA256:C7CwytJPJh7ZIlJO2EAcDyIPc0ZwrMd+0DrZhdUoE9o agent
debug1: Server accepts key: (none) RSA SHA256:C7CwytJPJh7ZIlJO2EAcDyIPc0ZwrMd+0DrZhdUoE9o agent
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "(none)" from agent: agent refused operation
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kostas/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kostas/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kostas/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kostas/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kostas/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kostas/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/kostas/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: What OS and version are you using?

Comment: possibly a [pin entry tty issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57116258/6309). The [guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GnuPG#SSH_agent) might be more complete.

Comment: @bk2204 I am using WSL on windows11

Comment: @VonC i ll have a look and update